# How to merge two hashmap data fetched from firebase in android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have two nodes Users and Plants

```
Users
  |
  |-plantId
      |
      |-image
          |
          |-imageLink
  |-plantId
      |
      |-image
          |
          |-imageLink

Plants
   |-plantId
      |
      |-collectedPlant
          |
          |-plantCount
```

The `plantid` in users and plants will be same. I need to get a `HashMap` containing plant id-imagelink and plantCount.

I have the two nodes data separately with me. Is there a simple way to solve it?

Comment: think of this as graph ds, you will be able to solve this

Answer (score 0):

To solve this according to the edited database structure and assuming that the `plantCount` property is defined as a `Long`, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference imageRef = rootRef.child("Users").child("plantId").child("image");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String imageLink = ds.child("imageLink").getValue(String.class);

            DatabaseReference collectedPlantRef = rootRef.child("Plants").child("plantId").child("collectedPlant");
            ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Map<String, Long> map = new HashMap<>();
                    for(DataSnapshot dSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Long plantCount = dSnapshot.child("plantCount").getValue(Long.class);
                        map.put(imageLink, plantCount);                     
                    }
                    //Do what you want with this Map.
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
            };
            collectedPlantRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);            
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
imageRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

As you can see, I have used nested queries in order to get the Map that you are looking for.